# git log <since> <until> shows all log instead of specified

Tags: git

git-log man page says:

> git log [options] [since..until] [[--] path...]
>
> since..until
>              Show only commits between the named two commits. When either
>               or  is omitted, it defaults to HEAD, i.e. the tip of
>              the current branch. For a more complete list of ways to spell
>               and , see gitrevisions(7).

When I do git-log for some refs of the repo I get the hole log:

```
$ git log HEAD^ HEAD
commit 1e939a4f7097efd03b8a66607b561c5f698b3082
Author: Vasiliy <dixel@unen.(none)>
Date:   Wed Apr 11 13:58:03 2012 +0400

    3 commit

commit 1da7dcfc1920130f3de9a7c6b8f02d68923d12b7
Author: Vasiliy <dixel@unen.(none)>
Date:   Wed Apr 11 13:57:50 2012 +0400

    second commit

commit ee8d884f5fb364f667f8dcbf27b23afb3a4eeb85
Author: Vasiliy <dixel@unen.(none)>
Date:   Wed Apr 11 13:57:31 2012 +0400

    first commit

$ git branch
* master
```

What should I do to be able to show log since and until some revisions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Didn't you just miss the `..` ?

```
git log HEAD^..HEAD
```

Comment: Yup, I think when git log is used _without_ the `..`, it just treats those different refs as the points to start listing commits from. So `git log feature1 master feature2 bugfixA` will give a list of commits that includes any commit that appears on _any_ of those branches (which will problaby produce slightly weird out-of-chronological-order output)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `git log HEAD~ HEAD` shows all content from HEAD and HEAD~

`git log HEAD~..HEAD` means git log includes HEAD~ and up to commits HEAD